# Java EE EJB interceptors

Tags: jakarta-ee, interceptor

Is it possible to have the default interceptor configured for all EJBs within an ear?

Default interceptors can be mentioned for EJBs within a module in the ejb-jar.xml. If there are multiple modules within an application, all modules need to have this configuration.

I am looking at enforcing certain interceptors on the application globally. So it would be helpful if it can be set at an application level or at a server level so that it is not left to the discretion of developers of the individual modules to include them.

Comment: off topic comment, would that be too much off filtering/intercepting?

Comment: The EJB version is 3.1 and I am using JEE 6 interceptors. The drawback is that the default interceptors has to be condigured in each ejb-jar.xml in all the ejb modules. The intention is to have certain audit/logging interceptors for all services exposed by the application. I found something similar in Spring ,where using AOP it is possible to configure interceptors at the service level. I am trying to find out whether JEE 6 supports any such features

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid having to specify the interceptor in each ejb-jar file, there is no possibility to define it on EAR level. Interceptor class needs to be packed in the same ejb-jar file as all beans that use it.

You can still extract interceptor's code into a common library used by all ejb modules, but still, in each ejb-jar file you have to define and activate a separate interceptor calling the common implementation.